# Customize Setup Project Dialogs

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

Using VS2010 - I have a winforms project that I needed to make an installer for, I have that all done and it works great.  But there's a lot of files in the Setup project I created and customizing all of the dialogs in the Unser Interface will be a huge pain.  Because I think I have to build each time I want to test/preview it, which takes a loooong time.

Is there a simpler way to edit and customize these User Interface dialogs?  I don't need to do anything too fancy.  Hopefully something like, "Make a quick change, preview it, make another change, preview it, etc."

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to build your setup? I'm pretty sure VS 2010 has no support for customizing the UI dialogs in setup projects that create MSI files. You'll need another tool for that.

Comment: I'm strictly using VS2010.  No additional plugins that relate to this matter.  You can customize your UI dialogs to some extent.  You can add text, images, controls, set conditions, etc.

I'm simply wanting to know if I can edit and test these dialogs without having to build the project every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom the User Interface Dialog, you can try [InstallSheild](http://www.installshield.com/). In vs2013, Microsoft use the InstallSheild Limited Edition instead of the the default setup project in vs2010.